# For $\alpha(x) = (x,f(x))$, can $\alpha^{-1}$ never be continuos because the graph of $\alpha$ is of measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, inverse-function

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 202, it is asked that

> Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^k$; şet $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be of class
>   $C^r$. Show that the graph of $f$ is a $k-$manifold in
>   $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$.

What I have done is that

Define $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ by $\alpha(x) = (x,f(x))$, then it is clear that $\alpha\in C^r$ is bijective and $D\alpha$ is nonsingular for $x\in A$. However, to show the continuity of $\alpha^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{R}^k$ by $$\alpha(x_1,..,x_k,f(x_1,...,x_k)) = (x_1,...,x_k)$$, I took a open set $C$ in $R^k$, but then realised that the domain of $\alpha^{-1}$ is of measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, and it is non-empty, so it is neither open nor contained any open set in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, so $\alpha (C)$ cannot be open, hence $\alpha^{-1}$ cannot be continuos, which feels like as if I'm missing something that is right in front of my eyes.

Therefore, my question is that is my reasoning correct ? If not, what am I missing in here ?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a mapping from $\mathbb R^{k}$ to $\mathbb R^{k+1}$. $C$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^k$. The expression $\alpha^{-1}(C)$ makes no sense.

Comment: @5xum Well, I should have written as $(\alpha^{-1})^{-1} (C)$; thanks for pointing out, see my edit please.

Comment: Also, $\alpha$ is **not** bijective. For every $x$, the element $(x, f(x) + c)$ is (for $c\neq 0$) not in the image of $\alpha$.

Comment: @5xum You are right, so I should restrict the codomain of $\alpha$ to $\alpha (A)$, so it will solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @5xum If you like, post your comment as answer, so that I can accept.

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is claiming that $\alpha$ is bijective. In fact, $\alpha$ is pretty far from bijective, as its domain is only the graph of the function $f$. Therefore, for any $x\in\mathbb R^k$, the element $(x, f(x))$ is in the domain of $\alpha$, but all other elements of the form $(x, c)$ where $c\in\mathbb R$ and $c\neq f(x)$ are *not* in the domain.